# how to add to an arraylist

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I'm working on a project which reads from csv file, then uses StringTokenizer to chop up the elements and place them into JLabels. So far I have that part down. I have buttons to scroll through each position, but I'm not sure about how I can type in the fields and add on to the array ?

This is the main part of my program so far

```
// program reads in csvfile.
private void loadCarList() {
    try{
        BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("car.txt"));
        String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();

        while(dataRow != null){

        carList.add(dataRow);
        dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();

        }

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception while reading csv file: " + e);                  
        }
    }
}

//this will click cycle through the elements in the Jlabels.

private void loadNextElement(){

    try {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer((String)carList.get(position), ",");
        while(st.hasMoreTokens() && position <= carList.size() -1) {

            position ++;
            String CarID = st.nextToken();
            String DealerShipID = st.nextToken();
            String ColorID = st.nextToken();
            String Year = st.nextToken();
            String Price = st.nextToken();
            String Quantity = st.nextToken();

            tCarID.setText(CarID);
            tDealerShip.setText(DealerShipID);
            tColor.setText(ColorID);
            tYear.setText(Year);
            tPrice.setText(Price);
            tQuantity.setText(Quantity);
        }

    } catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "youve reached the end of the list");
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way where I can just type in the jlabels I have laid out and add onto the array?

I'm kind of lost at this point, and am unsure how to go further with this.

Comment: Style comment: Don't capitalize the names of things that aren't classes. It confuses readers (as well as the syntax highlighter).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't tell what you're asking. Where exactly is the list, and what do you want to append to it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that you're trying to do too much inside one class.  It's possible to do, but not very well organized.

Create a separate class for holding a single Car record.  It should be simple "bean" or "POJO" class typically composed of some private properties and public getters and setters (aka accessors and mutators).  Your List of Cars will be composed of these objects.

```
public class Car {
  private String carID;
  ...
  private Integer quantity;

  public getCarID() {
     return this.carID;
  }
  ...
  public setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
    this.quantity=quantity;
  }
}
```

Define your list of Cars as a property of your current class, and each time you add a Car to your list, construct it from your Car class.

```
Car car=new Car();
car.setCarID(st.nextToken());
...
car.setQuantity(Integer.valueOf(st.nextToken()));
this.carList.add(car);
```